# What should I name a class that represents a list of lists?

Tags: naming-conventions

Lets say I have a class, called Foo, and I have a class representing a list of Foos called FooList. What should I call a class representing a list of fooLists? FooListList sounds a bit silly.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What does this "list of lists" represent in your domain? Most of the time, data structures in code model some existing data structure in the real world.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the data is representing.  It's a co-worker's code, but he offered icecream to anyone who could think of a better naming convention.  I'm pretty sure it is being passed as a data Provider to a Flex List component, but that's about all I know.  I don't believe that the context would help in this case anyways.  Mostly, I want to know if there is a standard convention for naming a list of list objects.

Comment: Sorry, my understanding was a little off. its actually just a list of objects, but there is the word "List" in the name.

Answer (score 0):

If this was an array of arrays, it would be a multi-dimensional array. Perhaps `MultidimensionalList` would be an appropriate name?

In this case, since it's only 2-dimensional, `2DList` might work as well (but it looks a bit funny)

Comment: MultidimensionalList makes my thinks of using FooMatrix, however that seems like it would be very confusing. I'm starting to think that FooListList might be the best option even if it looks really awkward :(

Answer (score 0):

You could take the plural form of the word for the first list (would be `Foos` here) and call the second list `FoosCollection` or `FoosList`.